# Mongoose- Error while upserting using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have got an error while doing upserting using findOneAndUpdate

```
ValidatedCertificates.findOneAndUpdate(
                 //query
                { "course": req.body.course_name, "batch": req.body.batch_name }, 
                { //update
                    "issued": false,
                    "certificates": req.body.validatedBatch.certificates,
                },
                { upsert: true },
                { useFindAndModify: false},
                function (err, doc) {
                    if (err)
                        return res.json({
                            "status_code": 500,
                            "status_message": "Internal Error",
                            "data": err
                        });
                    else
                        return res.json({
                            "status_code": 200,
                            "status_message": "Validated Successfully",
                        });
                });

        }
```

But I'm getting an error like below.

```
DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-
```

updatd
(node:14179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]

Is there any mistake while I am passing `{upsert: true}` and `{ useFindAndModify: false}`

Comment: try like this `{ upsert: true, useFindAndModify: false}`

Comment: @SuleymanSah. Now its working but still showing 'findOneAndUpdate' without 'useFindAndModify' deprecation warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace:

```
{ upsert: true },
{ useFindAndModify: false}, //callback function
```

with:

```
{ upsert: true}, //callbackfuntion
```

and at the time of connection to mongodb in  server.js file
pass configuration like this:

```
 mongoose
      .connect(dbURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`mongoDb connection establish successfully at: ${dbURL}`);
      });
```

Comment: Now it's working but still showing the deprecated warning,
(node:16120) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-

Answer (score 3):

[findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method signature is like this with options and callback:

```js
findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback)
```

Fourth parameter must be callback, but you send `{ useFindAndModify: false}`.
So just remove `{ useFindAndModify: false}` and it will work.

And to resolve the deprecation error, add this  `{ useFindAndModify: false }` option to the mongoose.connect

```js
mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });
```